# Weak measurement and distinguishability

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Suppose you can perform any weak measurement of your choice on an ensemble of particles composed of two equally sized sub-ensembles, but you can't use any other source of information about which individual particles belong to which sub-ensemble. Is there any way to use the weak measurement itself to distinguish between the following two scenarios?

1. Both sub-ensembles have the same weak value of $ +\frac{1}{2} $
2. One sub-ensemble has a weak value of +1 while the other has a weak value of 0

Comment: what's your understanding of "weak measurements"?

Comment: Weak measurement as defined by the group around Aharonov. See for example DOI: 10.1103/PhysRevA.89.052105.